# Does the Nystul's Magic Aura spell mask the auras of spells cast after it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does the Nystul's Magic Aura spell mask the auras of spells cast after it?

Suppose I cast a transmutation spell on an object, then cast [*Nystul's Magic Aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura) to make the object appear non-magical, and finally I cast an illusion spell on the object. Assume both the transmutation spell and the illusion spell create persistent magical effects that can normally be seen using *Detect Magic*. If someone looks at this object using *Detect Magic*, what aura(s) will they see, if any?

Comment: I think this question would be better if you were asking about a specific spell or list of spells, rather than all transmutation spells and all illusions spells. As is I think it's too broad as the answer may be different with different spells.

Comment: @AgentPaper: What makes you think different spells would interact differently with *Nystul's magic aura*?

Comment: @V2Blast I don't know, that's the problem. You would have to check every single illusion spell, and possibly even every singly transmutation spell, to be sure that none of them do anything strange that would change the answer. And even then, new spells coming out would further complicate things. Specifying specific spells or a range of spells that do similar things would help give the question a clear and final answer.

Comment: @AgentPaper: That doesn't prevent anyone from giving a general answer. I don't know of any spells that would interact uniquely with *Nystul's magic aura*, but if there are, they would be exceptions to the general rule.

Comment: @AgentPaper The point of the question is that there are 2 magic auras on the object, one placed before *Nystul's Magic Aura* and one after. The specific spells that placed those auras are unimportant, and the choices of transmutation and illusion are arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### They see a non-magical object

While Nystul’s Magic Aura lasts it does what it says it does - makes a magical object appear non-magical. The fact that the nature of the magic changes after its cast is irrelevant.

Comment: So if I made the spell permanent by casting it 30 days in a row, then the target would *never* show a magic aura no matter how many spells were cast on it after that?

Comment: @RyanThompson see above